# Android Speech Recognitoin Confidence Levels

Tags: android, speech-recognition

When the android text to speech functionality translates audio waves to text, is it possible to determine the 'confidence levels' of spoken text? So for example, if someone speaks too far away from the mic and the android device picks up distorted sounds, would it both output translated text along with a low confidence interval to state it isn't sure how accurate that particular translation was.

Answer (score 1):

if you are implementing the RecognitionListener examine this code clip from my onResults method.

```
@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    String LOG = "SpeechRecognizerActivity"
    Log.d(LOG, "onResults");
    ArrayList<String> strlist = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    float [] confidence = results.getFloatArray(SpeechRecognizer.CONFIDENCE_SCORES);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlist.size(); i++) {
        Log.d(LOG, "result=" + strlist.get(i));
    }
    Log.d(LOG + " result", strlist.get(0));
    if (confidence != null){
        if (confidence.length > 0){
            Log.d(LOG + " confidence", String.valueOf(confidence[0]));
        } else {
            Log.d(LOG + " confidence score not available", "unknown confidence");
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(LOG, "confidence not found");
    }
}
```

You won't see anything unless you add this to your recognizer intent:

```
iSpeechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CONFIDENCE_SCORES, true);
```

Comment: On my Android 10 device, `intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CONFIDENCE_SCORES, true)` wasn't necessary, but internet connection was required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In the returned `Bundle`, there's a float array called [`CONFIDENCE_SCORES`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html#CONFIDENCE_SCORES). From the docs:

> Key used to retrieve a float array from the Bundle passed to the onResults(Bundle) and onPartialResults(Bundle) methods. The array should be the same size as the ArrayList provided in RESULTS_RECOGNITION, and should contain values ranging from 0.0 to 1.0, or -1 to represent an unavailable confidence score.
>
> Confidence values close to 1.0 indicate high confidence (the speech recognizer is confident that the recognition result is correct), while values close to 0.0 indicate low confidence.
>
> **This value is optional and might not be provided.**

Please note that it is not guaranteed to be there. Check for it and use if present. Gamble if not.